# When normalizing list of numbers, result is all zeros

Tags: python

I need to normalise the values in a list to produce a (cumulative) probability distribution, but currently I'm just getting 0s out.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
tests = []
#some code to populate tests which simulates
count = [x[0] for x in tests]
found = [x[1] for x in tests]
found.sort()
num = Counter(found)
freqs = [x for x in num.values()]
cumsum = [sum(item for item in freqs[0:rank+1]) for rank in xrange(len(freqs))]
normcumsum  = [float(x/numtests) for x in cumsum]
```

Currently cumsum and normcumsum are:

```
cumsum = [1, 2, 6, 12, 28, 39, 64, 85, 96, 98, 99, 100]
normcumsum = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

How do I get normcumsum to contain cumsum/100?

N>B Yes, these variable names are a little stupid.

Comment: The dummy variable I'm using to refer to the members of my collections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x/numtests` will always return 0, much like `1/2` will always return 0, because you're doing integer division

You must do `float(x)/numtests`, or do:

```
from __future__ import division
```

This is only necessary in python2, not python3.

Demo:

```
>>> [1/2, 3/2, 5/2]
[0, 1, 2]

>>> from __future__ import division

>>> [1/2, 3/2, 5/2]
[0.5, 1.5, 2.5]
```

Comment: Thanks! I just hit myself when I saw it.

Answer (score 1):

when two parts of your division are integer, automatically python round the result and make it integer, you need to make one of them float. for example change "float(x/numtests) " to "float(float(x)/numtests)"